YOLOv10 ONNX Runtime: IndexError in Post-Processing After Exporting from YOLOv8 to YOLOv10
I'm currently upgrading my object detection pipeline from YOLOv8 to YOLOv10 and encountered an issue when running inference using an ONNX model with ONNX Runtime. My workflow was originally based on a YOLOv8 ONNX runtime script, but after upgrading to YOLOv10, I am getting an IndexError during the post-processing phase.
What I Did:

I successfully trained a YOLOv10 model using the pretrained weights from the Ultralytics YOLOv10 documentation.

I exported the trained model from .pt to .onnx format.

I tried running inference using a script adapted from a YOLOv8 ONNX runtime example. The script is available here.


The Problem:
During the inference process, I encounter the following error:
IndexError: index 91 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 80

This occurs in the postprocess function when trying to draw detections on the image:
color = self.color_palette[class_id]

It seems that the class ID from the YOLOv10 model is higher than the number of classes in my color palette (which is based on COCO's 80 classes). This suggests that the output from the ONNX model might include additional or different class IDs compared to YOLOv8.
My Understanding:
From what I understand, YOLOv10 removes the non-maximum suppression (NMS) step from the model, unlike YOLOv8 where NMS was handled internally. In YOLOv10, the NMS should be handled during post-processing, and ONNX Runtime provides a built-in NMS method.
Here is the relevant section of my postprocess function:
def postprocess(self, input_image, output):
    outputs = np.transpose(np.squeeze(output[0]))
    rows = outputs.shape[0]
    boxes = []
    scores = []
    class_ids = []

    x_factor = self.img_width / self.input_width
    y_factor = self.img_height / self.input_height

    for i in range(rows):
        classes_scores = outputs[i][4:]
        max_score = np.amax(classes_scores)
        if max_score >= self.confidence_thres:
            class_id = np.argmax(classes_scores)
            x, y, w, h = outputs[i][0], outputs[i][1], outputs[i][2], outputs[i][3]
            left = int((x - w / 2) * x_factor)
            top = int((y - h / 2) * y_factor)
            width = int(w * x_factor)
            height = int(h * y_factor)

            class_ids.append(class_id)
            scores.append(max_score)
            boxes.append([left, top, width, height])

    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, scores, self.confidence_thres, self.iou_thres)
    for i in indices:
        box = boxes[i]
        score = scores[i]
        class_id = class_ids[i]
        self.draw_detections(input_image, box, score, class_id)

    return input_image

What I Need Help With:

Preprocessing and Postprocessing Adjustments: What should be the correct preprocessing and postprocessing steps for YOLOv10 when using an ONNX model in ONNX Runtime? Specifically, how should I modify the postprocess function to correctly handle the model output and apply NMS?

Class Mapping: How should I map class IDs correctly given that the YOLOv10 model output seems to differ from YOLOv8 in terms of class IDs


Additional Information:

The ONNX model was created using the export command from the Ultralytics YOLOv10 library.

I am using ONNX Runtime with both CUDAExecutionProvider and CPUExecutionProvider.


I would appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to correctly handle the output of the YOLOv10 ONNX model using ONNX Runtime.
